# Show alert on validation rule

Tags: validation, standard-objects, validation-rule

Can you show alert message on standard page layout? when user change the lookup value and try to save?

here is my scenario, I have a lookup on a standard page layout and when the user change to any `Foreign Employer` and try to save then I want to alert a message

Is that possible in Validation rule?

[image]

Comment: no you can't show alert message.. instead create validation rule

Comment: You'd need a page layout to do that. Standard page layout doesn't provide such functionality.

Comment: It is only possible with Javascript or Visualforce. You can replace standard Save button with your own and bind some javascript on that button that will alert or redirect further. Or add visualforce to your layout.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, assuming Foreign is a checkbox on your Employer object, just write something like

`Employer__r.Foreign__c = true`

and have it display an appropriate error message.